# Upgrading Encrypted Local Database in React Native App

Tags: android, database, react-native, security

I'm developing a React Native app that stores sensitive data and currently uses react-native-sqlcipher-2 for encrypted local database. However, I received a notification from Google Play Console indicating that the underlying native dependency, android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9, is outdated. This raises concerns about future app releases.

I've explored alternative encrypted local database libraries like react-native-sqlcipher and react-native-sqlcipher-storage, but they appear to rely on the same deprecated dependency.

Can anyone recommend a React Native library for encrypted local database that offers built-in encryption and utilizes a supported native dependency for Android?

Comment: https://github.com/craftzdog/react-native-sqlite-2/blob/64ec364c7eb5b92fc3594c9b141c190b8c7be1d3/android/build.gradle#L63

Comment: Where did you see android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9?

Comment: You can typically find the version of android-database-sqlcipher by looking within the build.gradle file of the react-native-sqlcipher-2 library. This file manages dependencies for the library, including the version of android-database-sqlcipher it uses.
https://github.com/sreejithkrishnanr/react-native-sqlcipher-2